# How to make draggable DIVs which align to 960.gs or other grid framework?

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, grid, 960.gs

I am working in making an app around the 960.gs based system (although the grid framework isn't set in store yet).

What I would like to do is enable the user to drag and drop specific layout elements (DIVs), which would, theoretically, move the blocks of the design around. I know JQuery UI has a drag and drop system, which may be a component of this project, but what I want to do is make sure that the user can only drag, drop and stretch/expand divs according to the limitations of the defined css grid. And make sure that nothing will violate the boundaries of the grid, and generate the proper css classes to display correctly....

I have scoured the net and stack exchange for some examples along this line, but I haven't seen anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into a similar problem, and I found a few options that are not based on 960.gs.

jQuery EasyUI (www.jeasyui.com/) has something like this; here is a [direct link](http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/portal_demo.html) to their demo.

There's also [iNettuts](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html), which is something similar.

Since you said the grid framework choice isn't solid, I think these options might be useful.